# Advice on how to get started with building a home safety system using a Raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, wireless, home-automation, wireless-adapter

As a part of The IOT course, we have to build a system which monitors the house and notifies the client in case of any danger, for example: gas leak, house intrusion ... .

Having these monitoring devices connected with a wire to the Raspberry Pi I guess is a pretty straight forward project, But we want the communication between the Raspberry Pi and the devices to be wireless.

so my questions are :

- How can I achieve this wireless communication having that the monitoring devices does not support wireless transmitting, I've looked int Zigbee but I don't have the knowledge to judge if it is a good choice.
- Any other suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe pimatic-homeduino? https://github.com/pimatic/pimatic-homeduino, https://pimatic.org/pages/supported-devices/

Comment: your question is not specific to Raspberry Pi ... please ask a question that actually relates to the RPi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sensor devices cannot transmit wirelessly, you need to find some kind of wireless device that knows how to talk to the sensor.  If your sensor is very smart, you might be able to use some kind of simple adaptor, like a USB wifi dongle.  But more likely, you need a device that has a built in wireless radio of some sort, the right type of I/O to talk to the sensor, and enough intelligence to interpret what it is saying and send the data to the Raspberry Pi.  You need to think about the whole device, and not just which type of radio link to use.

Some ideas to research include ESP8266 and ESP32 microcontroller chips, which include built-in wifi and are available in a wide range of cheap development boards.  The ESP32 also includes Bluetooth.  Alternatives include Arduino boards or the Raspberry Pi RP2040 chip, which are also available in boards that include wireless links.  You can also add wireless links to most development boards: try Googling things like "wifi shield", "bluetooth shield", "zigbee shield", "433 mhz receiver transmitter" for ideas. Or you could just use another Raspberry Pi...

As this is a homework project, you're going to have to be able to come up with your own justification for your design choices, but here are some things to think about:

- How complicated is the sensor output? What will you need to be able to get useful data out of it?
- How many sensors do you need to talk to?  Will you need multi-point links?
- How far away are the sensors?  Will anything block or interfere with the signal?
- How reliable do the links and the devices need to be for your safety system?
- What are the power requirements?  Do the devices need to run from batteries?
- How easy will it be for you to design, build and program the devices, and integrate the link to the Raspberry Pi?  Are you better at hardware or software? Can you use the same development environment for the Raspberry Pi and your sensor?
- Does your system have to be compatible with anything else?
- How much is cost a factor?

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer, I'll do more research about the topic keeping the questions in mind, that's exactly what I was looking for, a list of questions and suggestions that will define my work frame.